# Failed at chromedriver installation

Tags: node.js, npm, selenium-chromedriver, npm-install, slamdata

I'm going to install slamdata on debian Jessie, as described [here](http://docs.slamdata.com/en/v3.0/administration-guide.html#section-1-installation), but I failed at npm install section and it wanted to install chromedriver. I even tried a mirror of chromedriver. Here is logs.

```
exec@mob-db1:/opt/slamdata$ npm install
```

> npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
>
> chromedriver@2.23.1 install /opt/slamdata/node_modules/chromedriver
>   node install.js
>
> Downloading http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.23/chromedriver_linux64.zip
>   Saving to /tmp/chromedriver/chromedriver_linux64.zip
>   Receiving...
>   ChromeDriver installation failed undefined
>
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.2.8-1-pve
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.4.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! chromedriver@2.23.1 install: node install.js
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the chromedriver@2.23.1 install script node install.js.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the chromedriver package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node install.js
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs chromedriver
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls chromedriver
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /opt/slamdata/npm-debug.log

```
exec@mob-db1:/opt/slamdata$ npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_cdnurl=http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver
```

> npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into 
>   npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
>
> chromedriver@2.23.1 install /opt/slamdata/node_modules/chromedriver
>   node install.js
>
> Downloading http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver/2.23/chromedriver_linux64.zip
>   Saving to /tmp/chromedriver/chromedriver_linux64.zip
>   Receiving...
>   ChromeDriver installation failed undefined
>   npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.2.8-1-pve
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "chromedriver" "--chromedriver_cdnurl=http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.4.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! chromedriver@2.23.1 install: node install.js
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the chromedriver@2.23.1 install script 'node install.js'.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the chromedriver package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node install.js
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs chromedriver
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls chromedriver
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /opt/slamdata/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue of a `yarn install` failing on `chromedriver`. My solution was to switch to the Node version specified by my application's `package.json`.

```
nvm install <RECOMMENDED NODE VERSION>
nvm use <RECOMMENDED NODE VERSION>
yarn install
```

Answer (score 0):

I met it with 'yarn install' which info 'chromedriver: ChromeDriver installation failed Error with http'.So i try to install chromedriver before 'yarn install'.
And then solve it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to install chrome driver through npm, use the binary files of chrome driver. Make sure you download the same version binary file as that of your chrome browser.

Go to: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

This will give you an exe file.
Put this file in user/AppData/Roaming/npm directory.
set this to PATH environment variables.

Thats it! You are done :)

Answer (score 0):

## Fix using nvm

1. Install the following node version `nvm install v12.22.12`
2. Start using it `nvm use v12.22.12`
3. Install dependencies with `npm install`
4. Go back to your desired node version `nvm use v14`

You should be able to run your project now.

#### Observation

I'm on a Macbook Air M1